# Debug Console in VS Code with Java support erroneously splits lines in output for sysout.printf/format

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, console, printf, newline

I have latest version of stable VS Code build installed in Windows 10 with Java language support by RedHat. I use jdk1.8.0_181.

`System.out.print()` as well as `System.out.println()` produce an expected output in Debug Console, while `System.out.format()` and `System.out.printf()` split lines in unexpected positions and also treat `%n` inconsistently. Take for example this code snippet:

```
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class PrintfTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    IntStream.range(0, 100).forEach(it ->
      System.out.format("This is iteration %d. Hello VS Code! Hello RedHat!%n", it));
  }
}
```

Try to run it. My output looks something like this:

```
This is iteration
0. Hello VS Code! Hello RedHat!
This is iteration 1. Hello VS Code! Hello RedHat!
This is iteration 2. Hello VS Code! Hello RedHat!
This is iteration 3. Hello VS Code! Hello RedHat!
This is iteration 4. Hello VS Code! Hello RedHat!
This is iteration 5. Hello VS Code! Hello RedHat!
This is iteration
6. Hello VS Code! Hello RedHat!
This is iteration
7
. Hello VS Code! Hello RedHat!
This is iteration
8. Hello VS Code! Hello RedHat!
This is iteration
9. Hello VS Code! Hello RedHat!
This is iteration...
```

I mean it's such a basic functionality, that there must be something obvious I'm horribly missing out.

Comment: i test it,and the same thing happens, not every time, but it maybe a BUG in the plugin,you could update issure to the official link :https://github.com/RedHatOfficial/RedHatOfficial.github.io/issues

Comment: This issue has been fixed in the lastest build. Here's the ticket: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-java-debug/issues/560